# RCP's ViewPart does not refresh?

Tags: eclipse, view, refresh, rcp

I use 'IFolderLayout' to contain two ViewParts. When I drag the border to control the size of the 'IFolderLayout' if the first ViewPart is active the content will refresh as the size changes. But if the second ViewPart is active the content won't refresh. That means the ViewPart will show 'blur screen'.

So the question is how to fix it?

Comment: Does the ViewPart refresh at the end of dragging?

Comment: Besides,if I hide the application into the taskbar，then pull the application out,if the second viewpart is active,the place it holds will show the desktop not the viewpart itself.But if the first viewpart is active,the place it holds will show itself.So I inferred that the second viewpart did not refresh.

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory for messages

Comment: I checked.There were no useful messages.